# Ember select two way sync with queryParams emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I with to sync queryParams with ember select
this is what is on my mind.

1. User can select an option in ember.select -> queryParams should get updated.
2. User copy / pastes the url with some queryParam -on pageload Ember.select should show relevant option selected
3. The sortAscending property may be mapped to order.
   I am able to achieve the part 2. Now I got confused how to achieve part 1
   **[J S B I N](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xiqituba/1/edit)**

   ```
   App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
     queryParams: ['sortBy'],
     sortBy: '',
     selectedOption: { id: 2 },
     options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'relevance', value: 'relevance' , order: true },
      { id: 2, name: 'First Name', value: 'firstName' , order: true }
     ],

     sortByDidChange: function(){
       options = this.get('options').findBy('value',this.get('sortBy'));
       console.log('optionid = '+options.id );
       this.set('selectedOption.id',options.id);
       console.log('selectedoption = '+this.get('selectedOption.id')); 
     }.observes('sortBy'),

     actions: {
       change: function(){
         this.set('selectedOption.id',2);
       }
     }
   });
   ```

****U P D A T E S 2 ****

```
sortBySelection: function(){
    var sortByOptions= this.get('sortByOptions');
    var selection =  sortByOptions.findBy('value',this.get('sortBy')) || {id: 1} ;
    return selection ;
 }.property('sortBy'),
```

View

```
{{view Ember.Select 
    content=sortByOptions
    optionLabelPath='content.name'
    optionValuePath='content.id'
    selection = sortBySelection
    classNames='pull-right'
  }}
```

In my sort mixin below sortBySelection should be **bound** to Ember.Select and its value should updates to the first object of the  sortByOptions (i.e {id:1, value: price, order: true }). But it is not instead the value is undefined and my Ember.select has no selected option. When user(I) select an option things work fine

```
sortByOptionsDidChange: function(){
    console.log(this.get('sortBySelection')); // <++++++++ undefinded ??
    var sortBy = this.get('sortBySelection.value') || 'relevance';
    var OrderBy = this.get('sortBySelection.order') && true;
    this.set('sortProperties',[sortBy]);
    this.set('sortAscending',OrderBy);
  }.observes('sortBySelection'),
```

****U P D A T E S 1 ****
Well I got a working solution which i have posted below. But i guess it is not a good way to do it. please help to find an appropriate answer.